# Canonical quantum gravity

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-gravity

I am looking for an introduction (textbook or paper, or if someone wouldn't mind writing a memo on it) to canonical quantum gravity, specifically the concept of minisuperspaces. I have been reading the paper of Wheeler (in Phys Review) but he doesn't speak about minisuperspaces, maybe they were not used/invented at the time.

Comment: Minisuperspaces are briefly described in the reference (Jonathan Haliwell's Introductory Lectures on Quantum Cosmology) provided by the OP in [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24033/).

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's Bojowald's *Canonical Gravity and Applications*.

For mini-superspace, hmm...Thiemann's book might be good. I know Kiefer's *Quantum Gravity* discusses it a bit, and contains good references therein.

- For **midi**-superspace models, there's a review article: Barbero and Villaseñor's [Quantization of Midisuperspace Models](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/open?pubNo=lrr-2010-6&page=title.html).
- There's also Misner's "Minisuperspace" (in JR Klauder, ed., *Magic Without Magic: John Archibald Wheeler. A Collection of Essays in Honor of his Sixtieth Birthday*, pp. 441–473).
- Ashtekar *et al.*'s "Minisuperspaces: Observables and Quantization" [arXiv:gr-qc/9302027](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9302027).

I think these should get you a good overview...

Answer (score 2):

How about [http://www.amazon.com/Canonical-Relativity-Cambridge-Monographs-Mathematical/dp/0521741874](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521741874), Modern Canonical Quantum General Relativity (Cambridge Monographs on Mathematical Physics), Thiemann?